# How to include a child class while deserializing json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a below class structure
I am deserializing a json string to below Student class using Newtonsoft json deserializer.
I am getting LanguageType information from json and I want to include LanguageType class while deserializing.
When I deserialized with

**JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);**

I am not getting LanguageType data.

I cannot change dto class.
I have to include languageType derived class only when json has LanguageType information.

Please help me with this.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }        
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseID { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public string SubjectID { get; set; }        
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
}

public class LanguageType : Language
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:
{
  "Student": {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "ID": "0123",
    "Course": [
      {
        "CourseName": "ABC",
        "CourseID": "129",
        "Subject": [
          {
            "SubjectName": "Test",
            "SubjectID": "11",
            "Language": {
              "LanguageName": "English",
              "LanguageType": {
                "Country": "UK",
                "Type": ""
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Please share your JSON

Comment: Why do you expect LanguageType? It's not anywhere in your type hierarchy.

Comment: I don't see how `LanguageType` is related to the rest of your classes.

Comment: I have added JSON

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have json file. how about trying this:

```
public List <languageType> _obj {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create C# model/classes based on your JSON data. You can do using vs such as copy your JSON data and create an empty file. After that

**Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes.**

Or you can use any online tool that converts JSON data to C#

After that, you can do deserialize it such as

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
```

Here T is a class which compatible with JSON data

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I cannot change the model. this LanguageType is dynamic. If I get LanguageType information I have to include this child class otherwise not.

Comment: @user11286517 you can inherit this class to another class that has LanguageType. Based on JSON data you can assign create an object of any class i.e swicth classes based on response.